# Prevent X11 popup (chrome download icon)

Tags: google-chrome, xorg, workspace

I'm automating chrome and using it to download files from a specific website (I have to use chrome, firefox is no good).

Despite chrome being on another workspace, it's download animation still appears on the current workspace. (The animation is of a blue rounded rectangle with a white arrow.)

Is there a way to block this specific popup or a way to block all x11 popups?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, [this and other problems](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=download%20animation&sort=-stars) with the [download shelf](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=download%20animation&sort=-stars) (and its animations) have been known for some time, but the devs have made little (in some cases *no*) effort to fix it. Unfortunately the most you can do is to add yourself to the ever-growing list of complainants in the hopes that it will motivate them to fix it (though it would be as effective as signing an online petition). Another option that may help slightly more is to open a new, more specific issue. It may get fixed faster, or at the least will get merged into one of the other download-shelf-animation issues.